# rails export csv return empty in production which works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I tried to export a csv file in my Rails app.

It works fine locally and if will return a csv file with data. However when push to production, it return a csv file which is empty.

Is there any possible reason about this problem?

View:

```
<%= link_to "Export Places", {controller: "admin/neighborhoods", action: "export_csv", format: "csv"}, 'data-no-turbolink' => true, :class => "button" %>
```

Route:

```
get 'admin_neighborhoods_export' => 'admin/neighborhoods#export_csv'
```

Controller:

```
def export_csv
@neighborhoods = Neighborhood.order(:created_at)
time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_s
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv do
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"places_export_#{time}.csv\""
    headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
    send_data(Neighborhood.to_csv(@neighborhoods), :type => "text/csv", :filename => "places_export_#{time}.csv")
  end
end
```

end

Modal:

```
def self.to_csv(neighborhoods)
CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  nbh_columns = []
  nbh_columns.concat(column_names)
  nbh_columns.concat(["maponics_neighborhood", "maponics_city", "maponics_state"])
  csv << nbh_columns
  neighborhoods.each do |neighborhood|
    values = []
    values.concat(neighborhood.attributes.values_at(*column_names))
    if neighborhood.gid.present?
      nbh_maponic = NeighborhoodBoundariesMaponics.find(neighborhood.gid)
      values.concat([nbh_maponic.neighborhd, nbh_maponic.city, nbh_maponic.state])
    else
      values.concat(["", "", ""])
    end
    csv << values
  end
end
```

end

Comment: I see in logs local will ‘Rendered text template (0.0ms Sent data places_export_20150825171859.csv  (0.6ms)’ and production will not, why??

Comment: Stupid question, but you definitely have some data in your production database for the csv to export, right?

Comment: When you say "it return a csv file which is empty" do you mean the controller action?  Can you make the csv ok in the console in production mode? If so, try taking the `headers` calls out of your format.csv block as they shouldn't be needed and might be causing some confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I copy the production data into local and find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the reason.

There is a bad data in production db. So one error happens when I use 'find' to search a row in db.

`NeighborhoodBoundariesMaponics.find(neighborhood.gid)`

Now I change to use 'where' and it works.

Comment: Even though there is no error information in log, it forbid the render and send data.